# Restart android emulator genymotion

Tags: android, genymotion

Sometimes in Genymotion I get this error that says

"The connection to the virtual device has been lost.

Please restart the virtual device."

I am looking for a way to restart the device from commandline if this occurs.

When I run adb devices the device is no longer connected to adb therefore making adb restart to not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
open -a /Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/player.app --args --vm-name "DEVICE_NAME" --f
```

--f forces the shutdown of the device